# ckeditor work in localhost but not working in web server(Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor. When I work in localhost (in my pc) it's working fine. When I work with it at my web server it is not working, only the textarea is shown.

I use

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

on the head section. In body section I use

```
<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

It works perfectly on my localhost but not working in webserver. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you get in the web browser console (F12) do you see any JS errors?

Comment: It showing:      No Javascript on this page

If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).

Comment: Then start by adding the type attribute :)

Comment: "No Javascript on this page"  Are you seeing that in the browser's native js console? Or in FireBug? FireBug has been obsolete for a while now and show not be relied on.

Comment: <script type="application/javascript"> added but problem remain same OfirBaruch i am seeing this on FireBug  @OfirBaruch

Comment: Do you still see the same note ("script tags have a type att...") in FireBug?